# Placing data types into an array using recursion

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, vector

I have this function which gets data (items[], predefined to hold 6 items) from a bag and returns it in the form of a vector. I am supposed to write a recursive array-based implementation of the method.

```
template <typename ItemType>
vector<ItemType> ArraySet<ItemType>::toVector() const{
vector<ItemType> setContents;
for(int i = 0; i < itemCount; ++i){
setContents.push_back(items[i]);
}
 return setContents;
}
```

How do I go about doing this? The data is already in an array, does it just want me to transfer the data to another array? Maybe I am just over thinking it, but the question truly has me confused. Thank you.

Comment: From what you have described I would say it is that simple but I dont think it would be.. can you give the exact words of the problem?

Comment: "Write a recursive array-based implementation of the method toVector." That is all they give me to go off of, sorry.

Comment: Well you can simply write a recursive function to do this it is just very dumb programming and i find it hard to believe would be a problem asked.

Comment: Exactly! That is why I am probably over thinking this. I just don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <typename ItemType>
void ArraySet<ItemType>::toVector( vector<ItemType>& setContents,int item) const{
    if( item >= 0 )
    {
        toVector(setContents,item-1);
        setContents.push_back(items[item]);
    }
}

template <typename ItemType>
vector<ItemType> ArraySet<ItemType>::toVector() const{
    vector<ItemType> setContents;
    toVector(setContents,itemCount-1);
    return setContents;
}
```

A recursive function needs to have a base case which is where recursion ends. We want to recurse the length of the array, itemCount. This could be written two ways, here the `push_back()` follows the recursive call, so we need to descend in reverse order. If it preceded the call, we would initially start at the zero index.